# value of environment variables keep disappearing

Tags: windows, visual-studio, environment-variables

Lately I'm having this weird problem. I added a path to the lib user variable of the windows environment variables.

I did this by right clicking my computer -> properties -> advanced -> environment variables -> double clicking on "lib" and adding `;` and the wanted path at the end.

I'm adding the following: `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\Lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Lib`

Everything worked fine (I did it a long time ago), but suddenly every now and then, lately every few minutes, after running visual studio, the path that I added disappears and I can't compile my programs until I add the path again. (It does not matter which program I'm running.)

Why does it happen? Is there a solution?

Comment: Changing the environment like that requires logging off and logging back in to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it happen?

Looks like visual studio resets the "lib" variable?
Using "lib" variable was a bad idea from the very beginning.

> Is there a solution?

Don't use "lib" environment variable for that.

If you only need to build the project locally, just reference absolute paths under additional library paths in the project settings.

If you're not alone and/or have a build server:

For windows SDK, installer should already create WindowsSdkDir variable for you.

For the prehistoric version of the Visual Studio you're referencing, you could define your own user variable "VC98LIB", set to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Lib".

Then, reference those variables (i.e. "$(WindowsSdkDir)" and "$(VC98LIB)") under additional library paths in the project settings.